# How to return a field that starts with a digit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I use ASP.NET Core WebAPI and i have method call that should return the following data:

```
 { "10v_module": 1, "core_module": 2 }
```

Since it is not possible to have a C# property that starts with a digit, how I will be able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just return a Dictionary<string, int> or a collection of Tuple<string, int>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be something like

```
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string s = "{ \"10v_module\": 1, \"core_module\": 2 }";
            jsonData obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonData>(s);
        }
    }

    public class jsonData
    {
        [JsonProperty("10v_module")]
        public int v_module { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("core_module")]
        public int core_module { get; set; }
    }
```

With JSON.NET all you need is adding JsonProperty attribute and specify its custom name that appears in resulting JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to give the property of your C# class a Json property name that starts with a digit.

```
[JsonProperty("10v_module")]
public string Tenv_module {get;set;}
```